# SD Card is not listed in fdisk but opens in files

Tags: mount, sd-card, devices

I recently formatted my SD card after installing android image for raspberry pi on it. After formatting the SD card is not getting listed in `fdisk`. I did `dmesg` and gave me the following result:

```
[29329.965881] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR50 SDHC card at address aaaa
[29329.968812] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa JULIE 29.7 GiB 
[29329.977085]  mmcblk0: p1
[29330.280006] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
```

then i ran `fsck`, gave me this output:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mmcblk0

    The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
    filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
    filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
    is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
        e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
     or
        e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

I ran `fdisk` and the output was following:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5ED03E36-159D-481F-BFFF-FB1F690C6077

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  781461504 898648063 117186560  55.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda3    1050624 781461503 780410880 372.1G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

I want to write another image to it using etcher. But etcher checks only `/dev` hence it's not reading the card. Hence not able to proceed with burn.

The sd-card is getting loaded in `/media`. Which before it incurred problems wad loaded up in `/dev`. Even though its getting loaded in media i'm able to copy files and  make changes to it. What can be done to make it work like it was before.

**EDIT**

output of `mount | grep media`:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /media/mi07/E type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Comment: Your SD card gets mounted in /nedia, it's device file is created in /dev ... What are the output of `mount | grep media` ?

Comment: @SorenA I have updated that in the question.

Comment: What was the device you ran fsck against, /dev/mmcblk0 or /dev/mmcblk0p1?

Comment: @Doug O'Neal it was /dev/mmcblk0

Answer (score 0):

First run the proper fsck

```
sudo umount /dev/mmcblk0p1
sudo fsck.fat -V /dev/mmcblk0p1
sudo fsck.fat -a /dev/mmcblk0p1
```

if this does not work, try `fsck.vfat` insteed of `fsck.fat`

At last
You do not need Etcher to 'burn' a new drive image on the sd card. You may launch a command like this:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/image.img of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M conv=notrunc
```

Comment: When using `dd`, be careful not to overwrite your own hard disk!

Comment: You can identify mass storage devices with this command `lsblk | grep -v loop`